# riverpod update state with image picker

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

> i make a provider for pick image and then when i added a new item to list it notupdate the state it added the image i added in item before it
> **how can i solve that issue ??**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

final imagePickerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<ImagePickerProvider,String>((ref) => ImagePickerProvider());

class ImagePickerProvider extends StateNotifier<String>{
  ImagePickerProvider():super('');
  final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  bool isImageChosen = false;
  Future<void> chooseImageSource(String pickerType) async {
    final pickedImage = await _pickImage(pickerType);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      state = base64Encode(pickedImage);
      debugPrint('The Taken Image in Base64 Is $state');
      isImageChosen = true;
    }
  }

  Future<List<int>?> _pickImage(String pickerType) async {
    XFile? pickedImage;
    switch (pickerType) {
      case 'Gallery':
        pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
        break;
      case 'Camera':
        pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
        break;
    }

    if (pickedImage != null) {
      try {
        final file = File(pickedImage.path);
        final imageBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
        return imageBytes;
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('Error reading image file: $e');
        return null;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  // void reset() {
  //   state = null;
  // }
}
```

> and here is read from provider to make an alert dialog
> **how can i solve that issue ??**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:waspha/src/colors/colors.dart';
import 'package:waspha/src/features/custom_need/presentation/widgets/picker_notifire.dart';

class PhotoPickerDialog extends ConsumerWidget {
  const PhotoPickerDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,ref) {
    // final pickerNotifier = ref.watch(imagePickerProvider.notifier);

    return AlertDialog.adaptive(
      backgroundColor: WasphaColors.white,
      content: Container(
        height: 250.h,
        width: 250.w,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: WasphaColors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.r),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text('From Gallery'),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.image,
              ),
              // onTap: ()=>pickerNotifier.chooseImageSource('Gallery').then((value) => context.pop()),
              // onTap: ()=>pickerNotifier.chooseImageSource('Gallery').then((value) => context.pop()),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('From Camera'),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.camera,
              ),
              // onTap: ()=>pickerNotifier.chooseImageSource('Camera').then((value) => context.pop()),
              onTap: ()=>ref.read(imagePickerProvider.notifier).chooseImageSource('Camera'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

> and here i picked the image and added it to circle avatar
> **how can i solve that issue ??**

```
class ItemWidgetExpanded extends ConsumerWidget {
  final Item item;

  ItemWidgetExpanded({super.key, required this.item});

  static final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _formKey =
      GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  @override
  build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Consumer(
                builder: (context, ref, child) {
                  final pickedImage = ref.watch(imagePickerProvider);
                  // final isImageChossen = ref.watch(imagePickerProvider.notifier).isImageChosen;
                  item.image=pickedImage;
                  debugPrint('The Image Taken Is $pickedImage');
                  // debugPrint('isImageChossen $isImageChossen');
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => showAdaptiveDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => PhotoPickerDialog(),
                    ),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 35,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                      backgroundImage: item.image==null ? MemoryImage(
                              base64Decode(item.image??''),
                            )
                          : null,
                      child: item.image==null  ? Icon(Icons.add) : null,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

> this where i added and delete items from list

```
final itemsProvider = StateProvider<List<Item>>((ref) => []);

class ItemListNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Item> _items = [];

  List<Item> get items => _items;
}

class CustomNeedScreen extends StatefulHookConsumerWidget {
  final isMenu;

  CustomNeedScreen({super.key, required this.isMenu});

  @override
  ConsumerState<CustomNeedScreen> createState() => _CustomNeedScreenState();
}

class _CustomNeedScreenState extends ConsumerState<CustomNeedScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isScheduled = useState(false);
    final isLogged = ref.watch(isLoggedInProvider);
    return isLogged.when(data: (data) {
      if (data == false) {
        return NeedLoginScreen();
      }

      return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: CustomBackButton(),
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Consumer(
                    builder: (context, ref, child) {
                      final subCategory = ref.watch(subCategoryProvider);
                      final category = ref.watch(categoryProvider);

                      return Stack(
                        children: [
                          Positioned(
                            left: 0,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              child: Image.network(
                                  width: 50,
                                  height: 50,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  '${category["image"]}'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            top: 10,
                            left: 20,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              child: Image.network(
                                  width: 50,
                                  height: 50,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  '${subCategory["image"]}'),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Consumer(
                  builder: (context, ref, child) {
                    final method = ref.watch(methodProvider);
                    final subCategory = ref.watch(subCategoryProvider);
                    final category = ref.watch(categoryProvider);

                    return RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "${capitalize(method)} direct request \n",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "${category["name"]}",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          WidgetSpan(child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "${subCategory["name"]} \n",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              width: 370,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                    )
                  ],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Craft your request",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: widget.isMenu,
                      child: Consumer(builder: (context, ref, child) {
                        final storeID = ref.watch(storeIDProvider);
                        print("ID: $storeID");
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            context.push('/menu-offer', extra: storeID);
                          },
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset('assets/images/nearby/menu.png'),
                              Text("Menu")
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Consumer(builder: (context, ref, child) {
                      final items = ref.watch(itemsProvider);

                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          String newItemId = UniqueKey().toString();
                          items.insert(
                            0,
                            new Item(
                                id: newItemId,
                                deleteCallback: (item) {
                                  items.remove(item);
                                  debugPrint(
                                      'The Item After Removed Is $items');
                                  setState(() {});
                                }),
                          );
                          setState(() {});
                          debugPrint('The Item Before Removed Is $items');
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Image.asset('assets/images/nearby/menu.png'),
                            Text("new")
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Consumer(builder: (context, ref, child) {
              final items = ref.watch(itemsProvider);
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  keyboardDismissBehavior:
                      ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
                  // Add this line
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => CreateItemWidget(
                    item: items[index],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
```

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).